# I'm reversing a string in C# using while loop I'm getting right output but same logic I'm using with for loop then output is wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is how I use while loop and getting proper output like this: "dlrow olleh"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "Hello world";
        string reverse = "";

        int length = str.Length - 1;

        while (length >= 0)
        {
            reverse = reverse + str[length];
            length--;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(reverse);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

---

but when I'm using for loop with same logic I'm getting different output which is not right for me and output is: "ddddddddddd"

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "Hello world";
        string reverse = "";

        int length = str.Length - 1;

        for (int i = length; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            reverse = reverse + str[length];
        }
        Console.WriteLine(reverse);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: You should use `str[i]` instead of `str[length]` in the for loop

Comment: note: every mechanism for reversing a string is broken in some way - usually related to unicode combining characters (diacritics, etc). Fortunately, reversing a string is virtually never a useful thing to do outside of interview questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Check this   [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w0BglI)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "Hello world";
    string reverse = "";

    int length = str.Length;

    for (int i = length; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        reverse = reverse + str[i-1]; // here a change
    }
    Console.WriteLine(reverse);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```